# Covariance of products of dependent random variables

Tags: correlation, covariance, independence

I have four random variables, A, B, C, D, with known mean and variance. As well:

- Cov(A,B) is known and non-zero
- Cov(C,D) is known and non-zero
- A and C are independent
- A and D are independent
- B and C are independent
- B and D are independent

I then create two new random variables:

- X = A*C
- Y = B*D

Is there any way to determine Cov(X,Y) or Var(X+Y)?

If not exactly, is there any way to estimate it? What if I could determine the distributions of A and B and C and D?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I did this correctly:

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Cov}(AC,BD)
&=&E(ABCD) - E(AC)E(BD)\\
&=&E(AB)E(CD) - E(A)E(C)E(B)E(D)\\
&=&[E(AB)-E(A)E(B)][E(CD)-E(C)E(D)]+E(A)E(B)[E(CD)-E(C)E(D)]+E(C)E(D)[E(AB)-E(A)E(B)]\\
&=&\text{Cov}(A,B)\text{Cov}(C,D)+E(A)E(B)\text{Cov}(C,D)+E(C)E(D)\text{Cov}(A,B)\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Note: The `E(ABCD)-E(AC)E(BD) = E(AB)E(CD) - E(A)E(B)E(C)E(D)`is an approximation in small samples. (In small samples, the sample independence may not be the population independence.)

Comment: There's no sample-level approximation here at all. All the calculations are in relation to random variables.

Answer (score 5):

A result in Bohrnstedt, George W., and Arthur S. Goldberger. “On the Exact Covariance of Products of Random Variables.” *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, vol. 64, no. 328, 1969, pp. 1439–42. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2286081. Accessed 22 Jan. 2024.
provides the general formulae. Assuming multivariate normality it is:

$$ \mathrm{cov}(xy, uv)  = \mathrm{E}(x)\,\mathrm{E}(u)\, \mathrm{cov}(y, v) +  
    \mathrm{E}(x)\,\mathrm{E}(v)\,\mathrm{cov}(y, u) + \\ 
                          \mathrm{E}(y)\,\mathrm{E}(u)\, \mathrm{cov}(x, v) +  
    \mathrm{E}(y)\,\mathrm{E}(v)\,\mathrm{cov}(x, u) + \\
    \mathrm{cov}(x, u)\, \mathrm{cov}(y, v) + \mathrm{cov}(x, v)\,\mathrm{cov}(y, u)
$$

In your case: x = A, y=C, u=B, v =D  and the only non cero covariances are
cov(A,B)= cov(x,u) and cov(C,D)=cov(y,v) so:

$$ \mathrm{cov}(AC, BD)  = \mathrm{E}(A)\,\mathrm{E}(B)\, \mathrm{cov}(C, D) +  \\ 
                           \mathrm{E}(C)\,\mathrm{E}(D)\,\mathrm{cov}(A, B) + \\
    \mathrm{cov}(A, B)\, \mathrm{cov}(C, D) 
$$

Which is the result of the previous post.

Comment: please provide full reference for your link in case it dies in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Title: On the Exact Covariance of Products of Random Variables  Author: George W. Bohrnstedt and Arthur S. Goldberger.  Year= 1969.  Journal= JASA

Comment: So this only works for Gaussian variables?

Comment: The JSTOR link is behind a paywall. But there's a free version here that looks like it's probably the same document. https://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/crmda_workshops/sem/Archive/sem-4/literature/Bohrnstedt_Goldberger_1969.pdf